# Stop divs from overlapping on table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div to recognize when there is a div already in its space and move down space.
In this example, I use a div (stuff1) that overshoots the width of its td and I want it to be accommodated and/or by other div (stuff4) in the overlapped td.

present table:

[image: image1]

How I want

[image: image2]

```css
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.red{
     background-color:red;
     height:20px;
     margin-top:2px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:2px;
}

.head{
background-color:aliceblue;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    
}

td{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>StuffList1</th>
    <th>StuffList2</th> 
    <th>StuffList3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="head">1</div>
    <div class="red" style="width:150%">stuff1</div>
    <div class="red" style="width:100%">stuff2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="head">2</div>
    <div class="yellow">stuff4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div class="head">3</div>
    <div>stuff5</div>
    <div>stuff6</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Simply add `<br>` right before `<div class="yellow">stuff4</div>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would need to implement the solution dynamically so a </br> would not work.

Comment: The first issue I can see is extending the content into the neighboring cell. Simply adding `overflow:visible` to the `td` won't work. Is a table really the right tool for the job here? CSS grid might work better bur would still have it's issues.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add one more div in second td like below,

```
 <td>
        <div class="head">2</div>
        <div class="red" style="width:50%"></div>
        <div class="yellow">stuff4</div>
 </td>
```

using this code you will reach your desire result, but I prefer you should use tr td tag with rowspan and colspan